# Setting up access point

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have a Tp-link WA701N Access Point, it was working fine. I wanted to change some settings, but unfortunately I forgot its IP address and login details, so I used reset. Now I can not access it. What I tried so far:

- connecting to it directly, an utp cable from its socket to the laptop
- connecting through the router with a cable
- connecting wirelessly to its own SSID

I tried every time with its default IP address (192.168.1.254), and some others (192.168.1.1 and so on), but never succeeded.

How can I access it, in what physical configuration?
How can I find out its IP address?

Comment: Does a connected system pick up an IP address?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, when I connect the access point directly, the laptop has the ip address 169.254.15.193

Comment: hm. That seems off. What's the default gateway listed?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is empty, the subnet mask is 255.255.0.0

Comment: Sounds like the AP isn't giving out IP addresses at all.